# How to determine the complexity of python code?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to understand the complexity of the following code. I am familiar with the concepts of all the Big O() notation and also have read a lot of blogs but I cant figure how to apply to big programs.
Following is the code for largest pallindrome number from 100 to 999:

```
def isPaindrome(number):
    stringNum = str(number)
    firstDigit_index,lastDigit_index=0,len(stringNum)-1
    isPalindrome = False
    while(lastDigit_index > 0 and firstDigit_index < lastDigit_index):
        #print(stringNum[f],"==",stringNum[l],"......")
        if(stringNum[firstDigit_index]==stringNum[lastDigit_index]):           
            isPalindrome = True
        else:
            isPalindrome = False
            break
        firstDigit_index = firstDigit_index + 1
        lastDigit_index = lastDigit_index - 1

    if(isPalindrome):
        return number
    else:
        return 0

max = 0
startRange = 100
endRange = 999
for i in range(endRange*endRange,startRange*startRange,-1):
    factors = []
    result = isPaindrome(i)
    if(result!=0):
        for i in range(startRange,endRange+1):
            if(result%i==0):
                factors.append(i)
        if(len(factors)>1):
            sumFactor = factors[(len(factors))-1] + factors[(len(factors))-2]
            mul = factors[(len(factors))-1] * factors[(len(factors))-2]
            if(sumFactor>max and mul==result):
                max = sumFactor     

                print("Largest Palindrome made from product of two 3 digit numbers(",factors[(len(factors))-1],",",factors[(len(factors))-2] ,") is", result,".")
```

If anyone could just make me understant step by step how to calculate I'd be grateful.

Comment: Emm.. Your code shouldn't work? you're not changing the indexes in the isPalindrome function

Comment: Are you trying to solve Project Euler problem 4? https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Comment: Yes and it does work. Now take a look at the function.  @GarethMa.

Comment: It's still O(n), the complexity is equivalent to the one i analysed

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, your isPalindrome function is literally incorrect, as you're not changing the indexes. I changed a bit of your also, so this is the version I'm analysing. (I'm only analysing the isPalindrome function, since I actually couldn't understand what the main function is doing), sorry!

```
def isPalindrome(n):
  num = str(n)
  head, tail = 0, len(num) - 1
  while tail > head:
    if num[head] != num[tail]: # Not symmetrical!! WARNING!
      return False
    head += 1 # move position
    tail -= 1 # move position
  return True
```

This code on average is `O(|n|)` i.e. O(log N) where N is the number. This is because on average, the `if` comparison has 50% chance of breaking (returning False) and 50% of continuing. Therefore the expected number of comparisons would be |n|/4 which is O(|n|).